# reversing shuffling of array by indexing

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, indexing, vectorization

I have a matrix whose columns which was shuffled according to some index. I know want to find the index that 'unshuffles' the array back into its original state.
For example:

```
myArray = [10 20 30 40 50 60]'; 
myShuffledArray = nan(6,3)
myShufflingIndex = nan(6,3)
for x = 1:3
   myShufflingIndex(:,x) = randperm(length(myArray))';
   myShuffledArray(:,x) = myArray(myShufflingIndex(:,x));
end
```

Now  I want to find a matrix `myUnshufflingIndex`, which reverses the shuffling to get an array `myUnshuffledArray = [10 20 30 40 50 60; 10 20 30 40 50 60; 10 20 30 40 50 60]'`
I expect to use `myUnshufflingIndex` in the following way:

```
for x = 1:3
    myUnShuffledArray(:,x) = myShuffledArray(myUnshufflingIndex(:,x), x);
end
```

For example, if one column in `myShufflingIndex = [2 4 6 3 5 1]'`, then the corresponding column in `myUnshufflingIndex` is `[6 1 4 2 5 3]'`
Any ideas on how to get `myUnshufflingIndex` in a neat vectorised way? Also, is there a better way to unshuffle the array columnwise than in a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `myUnshufflingIndex` with a single call to [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html):

```
[~, myUnshufflingIndex] = sort(myShufflingIndex, 1);
```

Alternatively, you don't even need to compute `myUnshufflingIndex`, since you can just use `myShufflingIndex` on the left hand side of the assignment to unshuffle the data:

```
for x = 1:3
  myUnShuffledArray(myShufflingIndex(:, x), x) = myShuffledArray(:, x);
end
```

And if you'd like to avoid a for loop while unshuffling, you can vectorize it by adding an offset to each column of your index, turning it into a matrix of [linear indices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) instead of just row indices:

```
[nRows, nCols] = size(myShufflingIndex);
myUnshufflingIndex = myShufflingIndex+repmat(0:nRows:(nRows*(nCols-1)), nRows, 1);
myUnShuffledArray = nan(nRows, nCols);  % Preallocate
myUnShuffledArray(myUnshufflingIndex) = myShuffledArray;
```